# Tunnel between local linux machine( behind NAT) to aws instance(linux)

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tunnel

Is there any utility through which i can create a tunnel between local linux machine and aws instance..

I used this http://www.rkeene.org/projects/info/wiki/142

Its good, but multiple connections don't work properly.

Please suggest me other possibilities

Comment: What's your intention, what do you want to achieve? Do you want to use the AWS instance as a proxy outwards towards internet instead of going through your own connection or how do you want it? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: The local linux machine is in a remote location. I need to connect to it through the amazon instance(and other machines), so that becomes a part of the private network, so that I can ssh and access various ports.  http://www.rkeene.org/projects/info/wiki/142 - works for me but i'm not able to use it properly with my AWS behind a loadbalancer

Comment: Tried any VPN solutions? Sounds to me like that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I see it's establishing a VPN connection between your external machine and your AWS VPC. You could just have an EC2 instance running OpenVPN facing internet on AWS, and set a client on the other end. You could even use Amazon VPN, but it implements IPSEC, which could be a little more tricky to connect from you Linux box. Another advantage of OpenVPN is that you can have as many clients as you want coming from anywhere.